# How to use Body of the Stream Story instead of Message in Photo Uploading (Graph API)

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

While uploading photo using Graph API, The caption of the photo should not be pre-filled. So, I want to use my app link shared with the Photo.

When asked facebook, they said, "Placed in the body of the Stream story".
But I didnt get any documentation and examples for this.

How do i upload photo with App link filled instead of using $message => 'some text'

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Policy IV.2](http://developers.facebook.com/policy/) says

> message parameter for stream.publish ..... Photos (caption), Videos (description)

as for me it means you still allowed to use description for photos to post your link, or at least actions.

Comment: I didn't get it. "You must not pre-fill any of the fields associated with the following products, unless the user manually generated the content earlier in the workflow: Stream stories (user_message parameter for Facebook.streamPublish and FB.Connect.streamPublish, and message parameter for stream.publish), Photos (caption), Videos (description), Notes (title and content), Links (comment), and Jabber/XMPP", You must not prefill. How do i post description for photos?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I posted a message to user's wall (/me/feed) with uploaded image Id ({"picture":xxxx, "description":"blablabla"}) to solve this problem. The description is for wall post, not for photo itself.